# Javascript/Jquery remove any break lines readAsText from a text/csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a button that allows browsing a txt/csv file.
Once users select one of those files, it will read text inside of the file and populate in the textarea.

```
    var JsonObj;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (file.type == 'text/plain' || file.type == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') {
        reader.onload = (function () {
            return function (e) {
                JsonObj = e.target.result
                $('#textArea2').val(JsonObj);
            };
        })(file);
    }
    else {
        alert("ONLY a text/CSV file");
        $('#textArea2').val('');
     }
    reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
```

I want to ignore all the break lines in the file when users select.
For example, if its:

```
abc,
def,
ghi
```

I want it to be populated in the textarea like this:

```
abc,def,ghi
```

Comment: `csvString.replace(/\n/g, "")` should work. Try it and let me know.

Comment: `$('#textArea2').val(JsonObj.replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/gm, ''));`. Why are you executing that Anonymous function that returns another function?

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick responses. @StackSlave this worked just great. I really appreciate you guys

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about the Regular Expression

```js
var a = `a
b`;
a = a.replace( new RegExp("\n","gm"),"")
console.log(a);  //it will print 'ab'
```